# Resetting the H2 incrementer

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, h2, spring-test

How do I reset the id incrementer in H2? Call it an XY problem, if you want, but my test fail just because the ids (`GenerationType.IDENTITY`) don't match. I clear the rows in `@BeforeEach`, but the incrementer is not reset hence the error

```java
package pp.spring_bootstrap.dao;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import pp.spring_bootstrap.models.Role;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest
class RoleDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    RoleDao roleDao;
    static final Role USER = new Role("USER");
    static final Role ADMIN = new Role("ADMIN");
    @BeforeEach
    void addSampleRows() {
        roleDao.saveAll(List.of(USER, ADMIN));
    }
    @AfterEach
    void clearRows() {
        roleDao.deleteAll();
    }
    @Test
    void findByAuthority() {
        assertThat(roleDao.findByAuthority("USER")).isEqualTo(USER);
    }

    @Test
    void findByAuthorityOrAuthority() {
        assertThat(roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")).asList().contains(USER, ADMIN);
    }
}
```

```java
package pp.spring_bootstrap.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String authority;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<User> userList;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    // toString()
}
```

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting ArrayList:
  [Role[id=4, role='ADMIN'], Role[id=3, role='USER']]
to contain:
  [Role[id=1, role='USER'], Role[id=2, role='ADMIN']]
but could not find the following element(s):
  [Role[id=1, role='USER'], Role[id=2, role='ADMIN']]
```

GPT suggested `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`, but it slows down tests greatly. It seems an overkill to recreate the context each time just for those ids to match

Comment: Why is the test concerned with internal database identifiers? Ah I see, you're just relying on Lombok's `equals` which makes the `contains()` fail. I suggest you determine what is equality, and whether the ID should be included (probably not).

Comment: @Kayaman you're right

Comment: Using `equals`/`hashCode` that relies on any field other than `unid` is __really dangerous__ when combined with JPA systems, because a simple .equals check can query half the database out as it walks down an endless tree structure of inner joins. JPA itself hasn't given a solid answer how to do this, so lombok can't follow standard guidance as there is none. -a lombok author.

Comment: My advice is mostly to just not use JPA at all, but if you must, I strongly suggest you check ONLY unid for equality, and consider the semantic meaning of an instance of Role to be 'it represents a row in the database that represents Roles' and not 'it represents a Role', because those 2 ideas are fundamentally incompatible with each other even though it sounds like that should be the same thing.

Comment: With all that context: You should tell lombok to generate equality ONLY on unid, and, yes, your tests should restart the auto-incrementer.

Comment: I'd write an answer as to that last one, but I don't know how. I know how to do it for postgres, as well as for h2, but I gather the intent would be to do it in a db-independent manner and there really isn't any consensus-standard-SQL to reset autocount columns. It's very complicated (the easy solution is to explicitly define the sequences, i.e. do not use AUTOSEQUENCE / GenType.IDENTITY at all), or to have no sequences at all (your UNID columns are java-side randomly generated UUIDs for example).

Comment: @rzwitserloot but what if you need to compare transient entities that haven't yet received their ids from a database?

Comment: @joreJoh That is a nonsensical wish. Either [A] an instance of your class represents a row. In that case, trying to compare 2 'rows' that haven't been written yet means that they are therefore by definition not identical to anything except their own reference (`if (x == this) return true; return false;` is the only correct implementation if not saved yet). After all, if you `.save()` both objects they'd result in different rows. or [B] An instance of your class represents a role, you should equals/hashcode on everything _except_ unid, and using these with JPA will kill your server.

Comment: I think most of the world thinks B is the logical answer, except B kills servers (add a JPA-derived object to a hashset and kablooei there it goes, querying the entire DB out and OOMing after 10 minutes of chugging away at it). So, JPA needs to be clear and explain that instances of JPA persisted classes __represent rows, not the thing you named it as__. But they don't want to do that because it destroys the faulty but pretty picture that you're just persisting objects.

Comment: @rzwitserloot what if you simply exclude associations from `equals()`/`hashcode()`? What's wrong with comparing fields of basic types that don't have their own tables?

Comment: @rzwitserloot also, I opened a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77129264/what-equals-implementation-should-your-entity-classes-have) since it's, in my view, an interesting topic that calls for a separate discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only test the `authority` of the `Role`, not the entire object.

```
@Test
void findByAuthorityOrAuthority() {
    assertThat(
        roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
            .stream()
            .map(Role::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .asList()
        .contains("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

A similar change is advisable in the `findByAuthority` test, since the order the tests are run in is not guaranteed.

Comment: `.asList().stream()` is not compilable since it doesn't actually return a `List` (instead it returns `org.assertj.core.api.AbstractAssert` which doesn't have such a method)

Comment: @JoreJoh Then what about at one level higher? Does roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority return a List?

Comment: You can't `stream()` the return type of `assertThat()` (that's what your current edit's code tries to do)

Comment: @JoreJoh Oh, I see what I did. Sorry, I meant to put that inside the `assertThat()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring ids is the way to go

```java
package pp.spring_bootstrap.dao;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import pp.spring_bootstrap.models.Role;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
class RoleDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    RoleDao roleDao;
    static final String USER = "USER";
    static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";

    @BeforeEach
    void addSampleRows() {
        roleDao.saveAll(List.of(new Role(USER), new Role(ADMIN)));
    }

    @AfterEach
    void clearRows() {
        roleDao.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void findByAuthority() {
        assertThat(roleDao.findByAuthority(USER))
                .extracting(Role::getAuthority)
                .matches(roleString -> roleString.equals(USER));
    }

    @Test
    void findByAuthorityOrAuthority() {
        var roleStrings = roleDao.findByAuthorityOrAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
                .stream()
                .map(Role::getAuthority)
                .toList();
        assertThat(roleStrings.size()).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(roleStrings).asList().contains(USER, ADMIN);
    }
}
```